# Number of solutions of $\gcd(a+b,n)=1$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $\gcd(b,n)\neq 1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $a$ and $b$ satisfying the following conditions

$\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $\gcd(b,n)\neq 1$, then

how many solutions for $\gcd(a+b,n)=1$.

In other hand, $a\in U_{n}$ and $b\notin U_{n}$ implies how many solutions for $a+b\in U_{n}$ where $U_{n}$ is a set contain less $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: I wiil reformulate your question for clarity. Also, I want to be sure that I have understood it. If this is what you are asking, I'll edit your question:

For any integer $n\ge 2$, let $U_n$ be the set
$$U_n=\{t\in\Bbb Z: 1\le t<n, \gcd(n,t)=1\}$$

Let also $V_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus U_n$.

How many pairs $(a,b)\in U_n\times V_n$ are there such that $\gcd(a+b,n)=1$?

Comment: Thanks @ajotatxe for reformulated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I wiil reformulate your question for clarity. Also, I want to be sure that I have understood it. If this is what you are asking, I'll edit your question:

> For any integer $n\ge 2$, let $U_n$ be the set
> $$U_n=\{t\in\Bbb Z: 1\le t<n, \gcd(n,t)=1\}$$
>
> Let also $V_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus U_n$.
>
> How many pairs $(a,b)\in U_n\times V_n$ are there such that $\gcd(a+b,n)=1$?

**Answer**

Let $p$ be a prime which divides $b$ and $n$. Then $p$ does not divide $a$, so $p$ does not divide $a+b$. This implies that $\gcd(n,a+b)$ and $\gcd(n,b)$ are coprime. That is, the prime factors that $a+b$ and $n$ can share are those not shared by $b$ and $n$.

Thus, **if $n$ is the power of a prime**, every pair $(a,b)\in U_n\times V_n$ is a solution, so there are $\varphi(n)\cdot(n-1-\varphi(n))$ solutions. Of course, $\varphi$ is the totient function.

---

*Let's see an exaple for $n$ that has two prime factors: $n=36$.*

We will search for pairs $(a,b)\in U_n\times V_n$ that are **not** solutions.

The set $U_n$ has $\varphi(36)=12$ elements. Since we should "leave" some available factor primes for $a+b$, $b$ should be a (non trivial) power of $2$ or a power of $3$. "Non trivial" means here "with a non zero exponent".

If $b$ is a power of $3$, $b$ is odd, same as $a$. Then $a+b$ is even. There are $\lfloor \log_3(36)\rfloor=3$ powers of $3$ before $36$. This yields $12\times 3$ "non-solutions". $a=11, b=9$, for example.

If $b$ is a power of $2$, say $b=2^r$, then $b\equiv\pm1\pmod 3$, the sign depending on $r$. Now, being $b$ fixed, not every value for $a$ yields a "non-solution". In fact, if $r$ is even, $a\equiv-1\pmod 3$, and $a\equiv1\pmod 3$ if $r$ is odd. There are six ($12/2$) posible values for $a$, for each value of $r$. Since $1\le r\le 5(=\lfloor\log_2(36)\rfloor)$, the number of "non-solutions" of this form is $5\times 6$.

So, for $n=36$ there are $12\times23-12\times 3-6\times 5=210$ solutions.

---

As you can see, finding the number of solutions for values of $n$ with several prime factors seems hard. You can try $n=5^3\cdot 7^2\cdot 11\cdot 13$. You would need to study, for example, values for $b$ of the form $7^r\cdot 5^s$, so you need to find the maximum values for $r$ and $s$, (which involves floor functions and logarithms), solving a modular equation for each choice of exponents, etc.

I really doubt that there exists a formula for every $n$.

Comment: If $n=p^{m}$, then number of solutions are $\phi(n).p^{m-1}$.